# Linker Error in simple program in Groovy

Tags: ros, libroscpp, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, everyone,

I'm having some trouble in the linking step of my program after running *rosmake*.

My program has a dependency in one other package, though I'm pretty sure that this console output isn't related to something on my end.

```
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linesmpSensorInterface: 10.4 sec ]                                                                                       [ 1 Active 21/22 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'virtual thunk to log4cxx::AppenderSkeleton::addRef() const'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'virtual thunk to log4cxx::helpers::ObjectImpl::~ObjectImpl()'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'log4cxx::Level::getInfo()'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for log4cxx::AppenderSkeleton'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'log4cxx::helpers::ObjectImpl::addRef() const'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'log4cxx::helpers::Pool::~Pool()'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for log4cxx::Appender'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'log4cxx::Logger::getRootLogger()'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'log4cxx::Logger::getLogger(char const*)'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'log4cxx::AppenderSkeleton::addRef() const'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'log4cxx::Logger::getLoggerRepository() const'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for log4cxx::helpers::ObjectImpl'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'VTT for log4cxx::Appender'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'log4cxx::helpers::Object::getClass() const'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'log4cxx::spi::OptionHandler::getStaticClass()'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'log4cxx::AppenderSkeleton::releaseRef() const'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'log4cxx::spi::LocationInfo::getLineNumber() const'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'log4cxx::Logger::getLogger(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'log4cxx::Level::getDebug()'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for log4cxx::helpers::Object'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'log4cxx::Level::getWarn()'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'virtual thunk to log4cxx::helpers::ObjectImpl::addRef() const'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'log4cxx::Appender::getClass() const'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrBase::~ObjectPtrBase()'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'virtual thunk to log4cxx::helpers::ObjectImpl::~ObjectImpl()'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'virtual thunk to log4cxx::helpers::ObjectImpl::releaseRef() const'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'log4cxx::spi::LocationInfo::getMethodName() const'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'log4cxx::AppenderSkeleton::doAppend(log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrT<log4cxx::spi::LoggingEvent> const&, log4cxx::helpers::Pool&)'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'log4cxx::helpers::Object::getStaticClass()'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'log4cxx::helpers::ObjectImpl::~ObjectImpl()'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'log4cxx::helpers::ObjectImpl::~ObjectImpl()'
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libroscpp.so: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrBase'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

By chance does anyone know where I'm going wrong?
(I could also be doing something completely foolish!)
Many thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51631/linker-error-in-simple-program-in-groovy/) by [Poofjunior](https://answers.ros.org/users/795/poofjunior/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2013-01-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Poofjunior](https://answers.ros.org/users/795/poofjunior/) on 2013-01-07**:
Ah, I should also post my additions to the CMakeLists.txt

19 rosbuild_add_executable(tempSensorInterface src/tempSensorInterface.cpp)

20 target_link_libraries( tempSensorInterface uniserial)

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-08**:
You can also **edit** your question to add additional information.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-08**:
Did you build groovy from source or install the Ubuntu binary packages?

**Comment by [Poofjunior](https://answers.ros.org/users/795/poofjunior/) on 2013-01-12**:
I'm using the binary packages.  Should I remove ROS and reinstall from source?  (At this point I've also now successfully installed the log4cxx library.)

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-13**:
The binary packages will be much easier to get working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bug in rosconsole. It depends on the log4cxx library but doesn't expose this dependency to downstream projects. For now you have to link against "log4cxx" manually (even you don't use the library yourself). The next release of rosconsole (1.9.40) will fix that.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-01-16**:
interesting, I did not know that, thanks for the heads-up

**Comment by [Poofjunior](https://answers.ros.org/users/795/poofjunior/) on 2013-01-17**:
I just discovered this when I removed roscpp from the CMakeLists findpackage() function and was able to create a successful build!  Thanks so much for bringing this up! To  manually link against log4cxx, right now I'm just adding log4cxx into my target_link_libraries(), or is there a better way?